# Pick date in flutter first year then month then day

Tags: flutter

I need a way to pick a date in flutter in the following order, year then month then day.
Initially I want to allow user to select only years and then in same way months and in same way only allow to select date.

The code I've tried

```
await showDatePicker(
                      context: context,
                       initialDate: DateTime.now(), //get today's date
                      firstDate:DateTime(2000), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
                      lastDate: DateTime(2101)
                  )
```

But I don't know what I want to specify more for the way I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add 1 line into your `showDatePicker`

```
showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: selectedDate,
  firstDate: DateTime(2000),
  lastDate: DateTime(2030),
  initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.year,
)
```

Or if you want to use with more features then you can use [Syncfusion_flutter_datepicker](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker) package